# Is it possible to to filter without id order? (Django)

Tags: python, django

I filtered by entering a list with this query : `listobj = Obj.objects.filter(name__in=listname)` However, when it returns the result, the listname doesn't have the same order as before. It's ordered by id. I would like to know if there's a way to avoid this please?

Comment: Exactly  what you want? Please share more details. You want to order as per your listname

Comment: I want that the order of listname remains the same.

Comment: the list ```listname``` change or ```listobj``` has not the same order as ```listname```?

Comment: ah yes it is listobj who doesn't have the same order as listname. sorry. no it is not ordered alphabetically. i think it is because i printed the id and it was ordered

Comment: I'm going to try it ! Thanks !

Comment: `Obj.objects.filter(name__in=listname).order_by('name')`. Is this what you want?

Comment: No it is not, the list is not ordered by name. Thanks for the answer though !

Comment: @Selcuk It worked ! Thanks a lot !! Have a good day !